# Use a Custom SMTP Server with Firebase IOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication, smtp

So I'm developing an IOS application that I need to be able to send password reset and account verification emails. I know that Firebase offers built-in methods for sending these emails through their own SMTP, however, I have found that their email delivery is extremely delayed sometimes. I signed up with Sendinblue and I'm able to use HTTP requests to communicate with their API through my application, however, there seems to be no built-in Firebase method to just generate a reset or verification link without sending it too. How can I generate a reset link then send it with my custom SMTP?

Comment: You can configure your SMTP server in the Firebase console. See my answer to the question I linked for details.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen when I do that and then add custom HTML in the templates, the email doesn't show the HTML correctly. Is there a way that I can generate the reset link without sending it and then pass it into my custom API HTTP request? I know this functionality is available with the Admin SDK

Comment: I don't think there's a method to generate just the reset URL in the client-side API.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen so the custom SMTP setting is practically useless because no server that I connect will actually send HTML. The HTML gets send as plain text unless I use Firebase's default servers. I want to be able to send an HTML password reset email using a custom server that has higher reliability. What should I do here?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen would adding the Admin SDK to a server be an option? Then I can generate a password reset link and send it with an HTTP request?